# Tkinter button.config() if statements

Tags: python, tkinter

I have buttons containing images which once clicked will change the image in the button.
If the image is an empty star then the button will update to a full star once clicked and again once clicked this option will revert back to the empty star image in the button.
I tried:

```py
firststar = partial(starsystemfeed, 1)
star_1 = Button(framefeed, image=emptystar, compound="right", command=firststar)
emptystar = PhotoImage(file='icons/emptystar.png')
fullstar = PhotoImage(file='icons/fullstar.png')

def starsystemfeed(num):
    global star_1, star_2, star_3, star_4, star_5
    global fullstar
    global emptystar
    if num == 1:
        if star_1.config(image = emptystar) is True:
            print("1")
            star_1.config(image=fullstar)
        else:
            print("2")
            star_1.config(image=emptystar)
```

but this doesn't seem to work as I keep on getting option "2" on the `emptystar` image suggesting that I'm doing it wrong

Comment: Try `if star_1.cget("image"):...`

Comment: it is an image that was imported through PhotoImage so I get    _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-emptystar"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```py
firststar = partial(starsystemfeed, 1)
star_1 = Button(framefeed, image=emptystar, compound="right", command=firststar)
emptystar = PhotoImage(file='icons/emptystar.png')
fullstar = PhotoImage(file='icons/fullstar.png')

def starsystemfeed(num):
    global star_1, star_2, star_3, star_4, star_5
    global fullstar
    global emptystar
    if num == 1:
        if str(star_1.cget("image")) == str(emptystar):
            print("1")
            star_1.config(image=fullstar)
        else:
            print("2")
            star_1.config(image=emptystar)
```

You can use `<tkinter Widget>.cget("<attribute name>")` to get the attribute back from the widget. In this case we want back the image so we use `star_1.cget("image")` and we check if that is the same as `emptystar`.

Comment: could you do it without creating a new variable as that would mean 4 more variables would need to be created? - code will be a bit more complicated.

Comment: @Bond007 the only thing (other than using variables) was the `star_1.cget("image")` but you said that it doesn't work. I have no idea why it raises that error.

Comment: comes out that I done  if star_1.cget("emptystar"): getting me the error but now that is fixed, It doesn't revert because I use the else statement but how can I specify the image that it should look for?

Comment: @Bond007 Try the code in my answer now. I think it should now work

Comment: same problem, doesn't change and stays at option "2". tried doing them as if and elif but this time it doesn't go through the statement.

Comment: @Bond007 Fixed the bug. I have no idea why that bug was there. It makes no sense to me. Now it should work.